# Parsing a file as an input with html and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, file, parsing

I've created a website with html and JavaScript, that illustates the K-means algorithm.
Moreover, I have made a simulator that works with an autogenerated random dataset.

Now, I want to give the oportunity to users to give a txt file with their own dataset as an input, in order to make the simulator more interactive.

So, I have created this form

```
<form name="myForm">
    <p> <input type="file" name="file" id="file"> </p>
    <br> <br>
    <p> &nbsp; <b> Push the button </b> </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value=" Start of simulation " onClick="validatename()"/>
  </form>
```

I have created also a javaScript function -validatename()- that checks if the user chose a txt file and up to now everything works fine.

Now I want to read and parse the file, But I have many problems with javaScript.
I read a lot and I checked many methods.

Which is your opinion about the best solution and where I have to look?
There is a similar example?

PHP(in order to move the file to server side)? 
HMTL5(but no compatiblity with some broswers)?
Jquery?
Pure Javascript?

I work with **Google Chrome Broswer**.

I try to find the easiest and safest way..
Would you help me?

p.s. Sorry for my english.

Comment: If your algorithm demonstration runs purely in the browser, then I would rather not get a server-side component involved, but use the _HTML5 File API_ instead. And I would not worry about older browsers that don’t support it in a case like this. _You want some? (features) Well, then first you gotta bring some! (an adequately modern browser)_

Comment: You want to parse the file on server or client (browser itself). If on server depending on the server scripting you are using you can post the file to server and process it there e.g. this link talks about posting on server using PHP: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp. If you want to process on client itself then I would suggest to read this article:http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=AKGQhnvbDXd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use PHP to move the file to a folder and then generate some Javascript with the path, something like:

```
<?php
    // Upload the file...
    move_uploaded_file(...);

    // Echo the path
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">var path = \"uploaded/filename.txt\";</script>";
?>
```

and then use that variable to read the file (through AJAX, for example).

Comment: I suggest this because, when selecting a local file inside the input file, it doesn't allow you to get the path (security reasons). So, there's no way for the script to know where the file to be uploaded is.